# Cross apply: Select vs Values

Tags: sql-server, cross-apply

Is there any reason to use `values` vs `select` in a `cross apply` statement? I've heard people reference this technique more often than not as "`cross apply` with `VALUES`". I find using selects to be more readable. Is there an advantage to one or the other?

Below is an example. Please note, I don't need help with what the code is doing, just trying to understand if one version is optimal, and why.

Using `VALUES`:

```
-- Using values in the cross aply
;with splitMeBabyOneMoreTime (value) as
(
    select 'a/b/c/d/e' union all
    select 'd/e/f/g/f'
)
select *
from splitMeBabyOneMoreTime a
cross apply
(
    values (charindex('/', a.Value)) 
) b (Index1)
cross apply
(
    values (charindex('/', a.Value, b.Index1 + 1))
) c (Index2)
cross apply
(
    values (charindex('/', a.Value, c.Index2 + 1))
) d (Index3)
```

Using `Select`:

```
-- Using select in the cross apply
;with splitMeBabyOneMoreTime (value) as
(
    select 'a/b/c/d/e' union all
    select 'd/e/f/g/f'
)
select *
from splitMeBabyOneMoreTime a
cross apply
(
    select Index1 = charindex('/', a.Value)
) b 
cross apply
(
    select Index2 = charindex('/', a.Value, b.Index1 + 1)
) c
cross apply
(
    select Index3 = charindex('/', a.Value, c.Index2 + 1)
) d
```

Comment: No, the difference is only semantic; if you compare the actual execution plan XML of both queries the only difference is the SQL statement text, everything else is *identical*.

Comment: One generally doesn't use VALUES for single row selects. It mostly makes sense when you have more than one row, since alternative with SELECT needs a UNION which makes it more verbose

Comment: Ok thanks @siggemannen; I thought that might be a contributing factor.

Comment: If you're dealing with something other than constants, however, then things will likely be a different story.

Comment: I normally use `SELECT` for a single row as then the column alias is next to the value rather than having to count ordinals in a list (though if it is only selecting a single column I might not care about this). For multi row I usually use `VALUES` though one case I do use the `SELECT ... UNION ALL` is when I want to add a `WHERE` to individual `SELECT`(s)